# Selenium Find Elements Of Multiple Possible Types

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to figure out how to get Selenium to find elements of more than one type, preferably using xpath.  For example, say I want to find all `a` and `span` type elements with the `id` attribute of `foobar`, I want the correct syntax for accomplishing something like this ...

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a OR span[@id='foobar']"));
```

I do not want to use the `*` regex wildcard; I want to restrict possible element types found to just `a` and `span`.  Any suggestions as to how to best accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`self` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/self) and `|`:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[self::a|self::span][@id='foobar']"));
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't even think to use axes.  Good call!